# Probleme with slice in react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Hello I have a problem with .slice

Error is : .slice is not a function

I want display customer commands's in a table but I have an error.

I get commands with my own API who return commands in json and axios convert it in a table

My Code :

```js
{commands.slice(0, limit).map((command) => (
    <TableRow
        hover
        key={command._id}
    >
    <TableCell>
         {command.title}
    </TableCell>
    <TableCell>
         {moment(command.date).format('DD/MM/YYYY')}
    </TableCell>
```

Thank's in advance.

Comment: There is probably a problem with `commands`, please share more of your code.

Comment: Are you checking if there is data in your commands before trying to slice it?

Comment: does it work without slice?

Comment: You should initialize the `commands` variable to an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fix the problem.

The problem is which my state by default was a list and I have changed this to a table and it's worked!

My old code:

```js
const [commands, setCommands] = useState({});
```

```js
const [commands, setCommands] = useState([]);
```

I'm just an idiot .

Answer (score 0):

`commands` is probably not an array. You need to check and see if it is an array or not.
To check whether commands is `undefined` or `null` you could add optional chaining like:

```
{commands?.slice(0, limit).map((command) => (...
```

or do something like:

```
{commands && commands.slice(0, limit).map((command) => (...
```

You can also check if the variable is an array or not:

```
{commands && Array.isArray(commands) && commands.slice(0, limit).map((command) => (...
```

Comment: `commands && commands.slice` will only work if the variable points to an Array. Else, there will still be an error, therefore this solution is not recommended unless absolutely guaranteed it is an Array.

Comment: Yes, and I assume since he is using `slice` he is expecting an array?

Comment: I'll update my answer for an array check

Comment: I have tried three things and for the last thing I have this error :

Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development. See https://reactjs.org/link/crossorigin-error for more information.

Comment: Checking both  `commands && Array.isArray(commands)` makes no sense. `Array.isArray(commands)` alone is enough.

Comment: same mistake when I try this